# await userEvent.type does not work when input has defaultValue

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-admin, vitest

I test my react-admin SimpleForm, it works perfectly in create context but provoke an infinite wait in edit context `<EditBase/>` (instead of `<CreateBase/>`).

npm packages useful here:

```
vitest: 0.34.1
react-hook-form: 7.45.2
react-admin: 4.11.0
testing-library/react: 14.0.0
react: 18.2.0
```

Form:

```
<SimpleForm mode="all" reValidateMode="onChange" toolbar={toolbar}>
  <TextInput
    data-testid="form.value"
    label="resources.values.fields.value"
    source="value"
    validate={[required(), maxLength(50), noEmptySpace]}
  />
</SimpleForm>
```

Test file create (working):

```
it('should be able to create element', async () => {

// ValueList contains somewhere the SimpleForm.
const { user, ...utils } = setup(<ValueList deleted={false} />)

/* Some code that open my SimpleForm **/

const saveButton = await screen.findByRole('button', { name: /ra.action.save/, })
expect(saveButton).toHaveClass('Mui-disabled')

const inputValue: any = await screen.findByRole('textbox', {name: 'resources.values.fields.value',})
await user.type(inputValue, 'new_value')
expect(inputValue.value).toBe('new_value')

const saveButton2 = await screen.findByRole('button', {name: /ra.action.save/,})
expect(saveButton).not.toHaveClass('Mui-disabled')

})
```

Not working test in edit context

```
it('should be able to edit element', async () => {

// ValueList contains somewhere the SimpleForm.
const { user, ...utils } = setup(<ValueList deleted={false} />)

/* Some code that open my SimpleForm **/

const saveButton = await screen.findByRole('button', { name: /ra.action.save/, })
expect(saveButton).toHaveClass('Mui-disabled')

const inputValue: any = await screen.findByRole('textbox', {name: 'resources.values.fields.value',})
expect(inputValue.value).toBe('old_value')
await user.type(inputValue, 'new_value')
expect(inputValue.value).toBe('new_value')

const saveButton2 = await screen.findByRole('button', {name: /ra.action.save/,})
expect(saveButton).not.toHaveClass('Mui-disabled')

})
```

However in edit context, `await user.type(inputValue, 'new_value')` provoke an infinite wait ! Except for element.value, it is the exact same.

In fact, in edit context all userEvent from `@testing-library/user-event` trigger an infinite wait, for example `await user.clear()`

I cannot use fireEvent as I need react-hook-form update that requires userEvent.

Please help me.